# HmacSHA1 generates different signatures on different systems using same secret

Tags: java, algorithm, oauth, hmacsha1

I have a jersey oauth provider that uses HmacSHA1 for signing/verifying requests. This works for my development & test platforms where client & server are both different physical systems. However, when I move to a production platform the HmacSHA1 algorithm (provider-side) returns a different value than the HmacSHA1 algorithm (client-side) using the same params & secret, and my oauth validation fails.

The JDK (1.6.x) is the same exact version on both the provider and client for all platforms.

When I switched my oauth provider & client to use the PLAINTEXT signature method (bad for security, I know), it works on all platforms.

When I dug into the jersey OAuthSignature.verify() method, it calls the signature method's (HmacSHA1 or PLAINTEXT) verify function, which simply signs the oauth elements with the secret and compares the value against the signature passed in.

For HmacSHA1, the method calls the Base64.encode() method to generate the signature, but for PLAINTEXT no encoding is done (as expected).

What could be causing the Base64.encode() method using an HmacSHA1 signature algorithm to have different results using the same params & secret on both systems?

Thanks in advance!
--TK

Comment: Hmm, the only difference I can think of would be different encodings of strings. Or a bug.

Comment: You're not being terribly clear, partly due to misusing terminology. HmacSHA1 *isn't* encryption, and Base64.encode() *certainly* isn't encryption... showing some code would really help.

Comment: OK, let me "try" and clarify my question. My oauth provider signature is different than my oauth client signature using the same params, secret, and signature algorithm (HmacSHA1), but only on one specific platform. This same combination works on several other "identical" platforms. The signature is the same when I change my signature algorithm to PALINTEXT on all platforms.

Comment: Are any salts used? Are those the same on both platforms?

Comment: Can you add some more info on exact platforms you are using? All I can say is that these problems are common, and I have been bitten by discrepancies; usually due to bugs on OAuth libs

Comment: The secret is exactly the same for both provider & client systems on all platforms, and the exact same software was deployed to each platform on both the provider & client systems. Not sure about how to use a salt using the jersey oauth client/signature libs. There must be some difference in the JDK or maybe servlet container in production than the other platforms, that is causing this difference, but I'm not sure what to check.

Comment: The platforms themselves, both provider & client are as follows: OS=RHEL-redhat-release-4AS-10.1, JDK=JDK 1.6.0_18. Tomcat versions are a little different provider=Tomcat6.0.24 & client=Tomcat6.0.29.

Comment: One difference between the production provider & client systems, is that the client system JDKs have been patched Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files, where the provider systems have not. I did not think that this was the issue because on my QA platform the client JDK has the same patch while the provider JDK has not, and I don't see this problem there.

Answer (score 1):

One educated guess: if platform encodings differ (quite common; some platforms use ISO-8859-1, others UTF-8, Windows maybe CP-1250 or whatever, AND OAuth library in question has newbie bugs where encoding is not specified when converting between byte[] and String, AND there are characters that encode differently on different encodings (usually anything but 7-bit ASCII range, characters 0 - 127), and you will end up with different signatures.

So -- you can see what the platform default encoding is; and force it to be same on both first. If this solves the issue, I would consider reporting this as a bug to OAuth lib (or framework that bundles it) author(s), or at least ask on mailing lists.

I have seen such bugs (String.getBytes("test")) VERY often -- it is one of most common Java anti-patterns in existence. Worst part is that it is bug that only causes issues under specific circumstances, so people are not bitten badly enough to fix these.

Another potential issue is with URL encoding -- handling of certain characters (space, %, +) can differ between implementations, due to subtle bugs in encoding/decoding. So you can see if content that you are passing has 'special' characters; try to see if eliminating them (for testing) makes difference, and zero in what triggers the difference.

Comment: Just for correctness: There are no ASCII codes over 127. And all the characters with unicode numbers over 127 encode differently between UTF-8 and all single-byte encodings (if at all).

Comment: Correct, not sure why I used term ASCII there. And yes, I am fully aware of differences between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-x wrt high range, that was the whole point (if badly expressed)

Comment: I just wanted to share the solution. Issue was not caused by encoding (thanks to StaxMan for the suggestion), but rather load balancer config issue, switching all https traffic to http (don't ask me why). The original request URL from the client is encoded into the signature (including https) & sent to the OAuth server, the server trys to re-generate a matching signature from the request (URL & Params). But, now the request URL has changed from https to http, so the signatures don't match. We fixed this by allowing https traffic through the load balancer.

Comment: Ah. Yes, https<->http was bitten me too. If termination is done in the middle, it can throw things off, since then server and client can see different base URL (https://... vs http://...).